# Building newer GDB failed due C++11

Tags: linux, centos, gcc, c++, gdb

I run 32 bit `Centos Linux` with `gdb ver 7.2` on it. I need to update GDB. I got errors below while building GDB 8.1:

```
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=gnu++11... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=gnu++0x... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++11... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++0x... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with +std=c++11... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -h std=c++11... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.
make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
```

My `gcc` version is `4.4.7` . Why it not support `c++11` ?

How to renew GDB in my Centos?

Comment: GCC 4.4.7 was released in March 2012 as a minor version to 4.4.0, which in turn was released in 2009, well before 2011. If you want more recent software, use some other distribution than RHEL/Centos.

Comment: may be you need gcc-c++
run this for try: sudo yum -y install gcc-c++